# Optimize the stored procedure replacing cursors

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have a stored procedure which is using cursor to fetch some data and then iterating over that cursor to update the enteries in the main table. I have thought of replacing the cursor with a temporary table but that is not helping actually.Any suggestions are welcomed.This is a sample proc i have created for testing.

My procedure is as follows:

```
**CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.modify_process_hr_change_log
IS
   v_ddl       VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_dropddl   VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_execsql   VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_dt_max    VARCHAR2 (1000)
      :=    EXTRACT (HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
         || ':'
         || EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
         || ':'
         || EXTRACT (SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
BEGIN
--   SAVEPOINT mdfy_process_hr_change_log;
   BEGIN
      v_dropddl := 'DROP TABLE temp_AttuidChange';
      v_ddl :=
         'CREATE TABLE temp_AttuidChange
  AS (select
sup.id as id,
sup.name as name,
sup.role as role,
sup.technology as technology
from
main hr,
secondary sup
where
 sup.id=hr.id) ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ddl;
      COMMIT;
   END;
--dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time);
   -- update records in main tables from the temporary table
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' UPDATE main t1
      SET (t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.ROLE, t1.technology) =
             (SELECT t2.ID, t2.NAME, t2.ROLE, t2.technology
                FROM temp_AttuidChange t2
               WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM temp_attuidchange
                   WHERE temp_attuidchange.ID = t1.ID)';
   COMMIT;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dropddl;
--dbms_output.put_line(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) || ':' ||EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|| ':' ||EXTRACT(SECOND FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
END;
/**
```

Original procedure using cursors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.process_hr_change_log1
IS
cursor cur_attuid_change is
select
sup.id as id,
sup.name as name,
sup.role as role,
sup.technology as technology
from
main hr,
secondary sup
where
 sup.id=hr.id;

BEGIN


   -- update records in main tables from the cursor
   for rec_attuid_change in cur_attuid_change loop

    update main t1
    set    t1.id    = rec_attuid_change.id,
    t1.name    = rec_attuid_change.name,
   t1.ROLE=rec_attuid_change.role,
   t1.technology=rec_attuid_change.technology
    where    t1.id = rec_attuid_change.id;
    commit;

    update main1 t1
    set    t1.id    = rec_attuid_change.id,
    t1.name    = rec_attuid_change.name,
   t1.ROLE=rec_attuid_change.role,
   t1.technology=rec_attuid_change.technology
    where    t1.id = rec_attuid_change.id;
    commit;

    update main2 t1
    set    t1.id    = rec_attuid_change.id,
    t1.name    = rec_attuid_change.name,
   t1.ROLE=rec_attuid_change.role,
   t1.technology=rec_attuid_change.technology
    where    t1.id = rec_attuid_change.id;
    commit;
   end loop;


END;
/
```

Comment: If you were going to use that approach you should use a global temporary table, not create a normal table on the fly. The dynamic SQL isn't exactly making life any easier. Maybe you should look at a single correlated update instead of doing lots of individual updates in a loop; or using a collection and a bulk update? Rewriting your code for you is too broad though.

Comment: @AlexPoole : I have different update queries for different tables.This is just a sample.So may be it wont be possible in a single correlated update, probably i am not very good in that.So how exactly global temp table may help !!